# When I click on a UIButton it should return a value I assigned

Tags: uibutton, ios7

How to assign a value to UIButton so that when I click it, it should return me that value.
For EX : if i have 10 buttons and when i click first button it should return me 01 and when i click second button it should return me 02 and so on.

Answer (score 2):

**Set tag value**  for each button and access the value from button action like buttonname.tag.

Set tag value :

[image]

And get the tag value from action of the button like this

```
- (IBAction)doMyAction:(UIButton *)sender {

    NSLog(@"Selected Button %d",sender.tag);
}
```

if your creating programmatically do like this :

```
UIButton *button1 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,100,50,50)];
button1.tag = 01;
```

And retrieve as same above.